# How can I make a text to the next line after a fullstop or a condition in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am having a string that is to fetch from my API like this.

1)Open your browser.2) Go to settings.3) Click on developers mode.

So I am to display the string above in a text widget. But what I want is for it to break to the next line from where there is a full stop. So that in the text widget it will appear like this.

```
    1) Open your browser.
    2) Go to settings.
    3) Click on developers mode.



 Text(
      '${fetched_string}',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    )
```

How can I achieve that or Is there a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
'${fetched_string}'.replaceAll(".", ".\n");
```

This should replace all fullstops with a full stop and a new line. Please note that it will replace all fullstops. So make sure you don't get fullstops in between sentenses